# if df confition is met add x value to variable

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to try is, if df confition is met add x value to variable

example

```
local_bid = 0
df.loc[["Entity"] == "Keyword"]
```

then

```
local_bid = df["Bid"]
```

I tried the

```
df.loc[["Entity"] == "Keyword", local_bid] = df["Bid"]
```

but it didn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaumne/Desktop/zorba/Sp_limpr.py", line 17, in <module>
    s =limpr.loc[["Entity"] == "Keyword", local_bid] = limpr["Bid"]
  File "/home/shaumne/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 818, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
  File "/home/shaumne/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1703, in _setitem_with_indexer
    key, _ = convert_missing_indexer(idx)
  File "/home/shaumne/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2585, in convert_missing_indexer
    raise KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem")
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need compare column `df["Entity"]` not list `["Entity"]`:

```
local_bid = 0

df.loc[df["Entity"] == "Keyword", local_bid] = df["Bid"]
```